# Can someone please explain an example from Eckel's "On Java 8" book regarding interfaces?

Tags: java

So, we got such an example in which we are making a new interface RandomDoubles:

```
import java.util.*;

public interface RandomDoubles {
  Random RAND = new Random(47);
  default double next() { return RAND.nextDouble(); }
  static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomDoubles rd = new RandomDoubles() {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i ++)
      System.out.print(rd.next() + " ");
  }
}
/* Output:
0.7271157860730044 0.5309454508634242
0.16020656493302599 0.18847866977771732
0.5166020801268457 0.2678662084200585
0.2613610344283964
*/
```

`

and I'm confused with this particular line:

```
`RandomDoubles rd = new RandomDoubles() {};`
```

As I understand a variable of type of interface can reference an object of class which implemets that interface.

Where do we have in this example such an implementation? Why we got such reference in that particular line?

Comment: It's an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Since it's an interface, there's noway to initialize it using `RandomDoubles rd = new RandomDoubles();` but as the interface doesn't have any abstract methods, it can be implemented without actually implementing anything, hence `{}`

Comment: `new RandomDoubles() {}` _is_ the implementation; it's called an  **anonymous class**.

Comment: wow, *that* compiles! I'm impressed. A java program without a single explicitly declared class!!